# Implement ArcGIS Custom Features with C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, .net

Is it possible to implement [custom features](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/ExtendingArcObjects/Ch07/TreeCustomFeature.htm) in .NET?

If so, how?

I suspect the issue is being able to do [COM aggregation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3k086s0%28VS.71%29.aspx#cpconinheritanceaggregationcontainmentanchor2) with .NET, but I can't find anything on that ...

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a <del>runtime</del> COM callable wrapper for a .NET class that supports COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_AGGREGATE_BLIND ?

Comment: Wouldn't you be creating a COM-callable wrapper (CCW) rather than a runtime-callable wrapper (RCW), since you're going to publish a managed (.NET) co-class to an unmanaged framework (ArcObjects)?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect new features in .NET 4 where implementing COM aggregation is actually possible.

Comment: Also, while I don't have any proof for this, it seems that Managed C++ grants you some more freedom when dealing with COM. In case that you don't find a good way to do this with C#, you could have a look at Managed C++ for the critical pieces of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be unable to implement pure COM aggregation in .NET 3.5 or lower, but you may be lucky in .NET 4, which adds the new [ICustomQueryInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386862.aspx) interface, allowing you to redirect the interface queries properly. More information with a sample included can be found on [codeplex](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/32350).

I also recommend to proceed along the C++ ESRI docs [sample](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/ExtendingArcObjects/Ch07/TreeCustomFeature.htm). The link is for 9.0, but I suspect this particular sample has not changed one bit.

Comment: Since this problem interests me a lot, I'll try to port the ESRI's sample to .NET 4 C#.

Comment: Hey Petr, that would be great to have a C# version of the sample!  Even though the ArcGIS 10.0 PIA's are for 3.5, I guess custom features can still be 4.0(?) I'll add a bounty to this question in a couple of days.

Comment: @Petr how's that sample coming ;)

Comment: @blah238: turned out it's not that easy as it looked like.. ;) There is not much documentation or samples as to .NET COM aggregation out there. I'll try to come back to it.

Comment: @Kirk: BTW - We ran into some really strange issues when trying to do extensions using .NET 4 - so I wouldn't recommend it.  I ended up having to backport a ton of our code to 3.5sp1 to get things to work properly, at least with 10sp1.  (One example - subscribing to certain document events, and doing nothing else, will disable right click menus in ArcMap - even though it's totally unrelated functionality...)