# Use existing property pages with new IFeatureRenderer

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcmap, arcscene

I am trying to override the drawing of a feature within a custom plugin data source.  I believe this entails making a custom `IFeatureRenderer`.

However, the "renderer" I'd like to design would be 99% the same as a [ClassBreaksRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ClassBreaksRendererClass_Class/001200000050000000/), but with a custom [Draw](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Draw_Method/0012000004wq000000/) override.

What would be the simplest manner to be able to reuse the existing functionality of the [ClassBreaksRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ClassBreaksRendererClass_Class/001200000050000000/) (including and especially the UI property pages) while still being able to provide a custom `Draw` implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since for feature renderers, it is the property page that is registered so that it appears in the UI (renderers themselves are not registered), your best bet is to implement your own property page and relay all (or most) of its calls to an [GraduatedColorPropertyPage](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GraduatedColorPropertyPageClass_Class/001300000042000000/) instance. This class is the property page for class breaks renderers.

Now, for the feature renderer, you have two options.

1. You implement your own from scratch. You will need to implement most of the interfaces the [ClassBreaksRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ClassBreaksRendererClass_Class/001200000050000000/) class does as the property page surely relies on them to be implemented.
2. Again, similarly to the property page, you use composition. Create an instance of `ClassBreaksRenderer` and route all calls (on all of its interfaces) except possibly the `Draw` method to that inner instance.

It is clear that option 2 is way more convenient.

EDIT: For both classes, you need to pay attention to methods which return GUIDs or create object instances. Those methods are not routed to an inner instance since you need to return a different, correct GUIDs or instances for your classes. This is the case of:

1. [IRendererPropertyPage.ClassID](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0013/0013000000r6000000.htm), [IRendererPropertyPage.RendererClassID](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/RendererClassID_Property/0013000000rm000000/), [IPropertyPageContext.CreateCompatibleObject](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0023/0023000000t2000000.htm) for the property page class.
2. [IPersistStream.GetClassID](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0042/00420000017p000000.htm), [IPersist.GetClassID](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0042/00420000017p000000.htm) for the renderer.

There is a cleaner way to do that, called COM aggregation. Query interfaces are pointed to the inner instance automatically so that you do not need to implement them on the outer instance (unless you want to override them). Also, COM aggregation ensures that should the author of the inner class add new interfaces in a future release, your outer class will support them as well. Unfortunately COM aggregation can be done only in C++, it's not (as far as I know) possible in .NET runtimes 1.1 or 2.0. There are some new features for custom COM interface querying (which should make COM aggregation possible) in .NET 4, but I have yet to see a working sample.

Comment: About the COM aggregation bit, here is an [example from StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981013/managed-com-aggregation/1981171#1981171) on using it in .NET 4. Not much use to ArcGIS developers yet, but at least MS isn't forgetting about COM.

Comment: Yeah, we have discussed this with Kirk some time ago in context of custom features. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/572/implement-arcgis-custom-features-with-c

Comment: +1 For option 2, I wonder if there's some Visual Studio tool that would generate the code for this.  Also, you might look at [ILayerExtensionDraw](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000731000000) if you want to decorate what OOTB Draw does.

Comment: @Kirk, when you go to [implement an interface in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1s9z1w%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), there should be an option to automatically stub out its members -- is this what you meant?

Comment: Well, I've gone through and done this (using method 2), and for some reason, it seems like the `GraduatedColorPropertyPage` will automatically create a new `ClassBreaksRenderer` that *replaces* mine, so this doesn't work.  It works the first time through, but then the property page (via composition) "kills" the renderer I generate, which means my draw routine never gets called.

Comment: You need to create your own property page and route all of its method calls (except IRendererPropertyPage.RendererClassID) to an inner instance of GraduatedColorPropertyPage. In IRendererPropertyPage.RendererClassID, you return your renderer's GUID.

Comment: You may also need to implement IPropertyPageContext.CreateCompatibleObject differently (and not route it to the inner instance), since the implementation in GraduatedColorPropertyPage will also create a new instance of ClassBreaksRenderer, which is not what you want. Create your own renderer instance here. See the sample for custom multivariate renderer property page: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Multivariate_renderer/000100000m76000000/

Comment: @Petr: Yes, that was the key... The other requirement was to override (in both classes) the methods that return the COM GUIDs (which was the one I missed previously).  This works great, though it's a fair amount of work ;)  Thanks for the help - now for some follow-up questions.

Comment: @Reed: thanks, I updated the answer. If there are any methods missing, feel free to edit the answer further.

Comment: @blah238 I wish Visual Studio had a tool that I could point to something like the classbreaksrenderer class and have it generate code for a new class that contains it.  The containing class would implement all the interfaces of the contained class and simply forward all calls to the contained class.  I would then be able to go in and override the methods (e.g. IFeatureRenderer.Draw), in effect doing inheritance.  Seems like there should be a way using PIA's to query a coclass and get a list of all interfaces it implements.  If so, such a tool could be developed.

Comment: Petr: I believe those were the main ones that couldn't be directly mapped through.  @Kirk: I agree completely - there have been many requests over the years for a tool that will implement one or more interfaces via composition.  It'd have made life a lot easier here, since there were so many required methods.  Now I just have to get my drawing issues figured out, and I'm set :)  Thanks guys.

Comment: Peter & @Kirk: Turns out this only somewhat works.  The problem is, when you do this, the standard property page assumes your renderer is one it should work with, so every time you edit symbology, it seems to "take over" and use itself instead of the encapsulated property page.  Not sure how to avoid that, though the rendering still works...