# Custom Layer Properties

Tags: arcmap, feature-layer

I am coding a custom layer for ArcMap using C#. I want the eleven standard property pages to display for the layer (General, Source, Selection, ... , HTML Popup), when the user selects Properties from the TOC context menu. I have not been able to find documentation that associates each page with the interface(s) that it requires. (Other than the General Page which requires ILayer). Anyone have a list that associates the property pages and their interfaces? I suspect that if my custom layer class implements those interfaces, those pages will display. If I am taking the wrong approach, then how do I get those property pages to appear for my custom layer?

Thanks,
Steve

---

Thanks for your attention.

I read those articles before making my post.  They describe how to create a property page for my layer.  What I am looking for is how to get the eleven standard property pages to appear for my feature layer, when the user selects "Properties" from the TOC context menu, for a feature layer.

For example:  The first standard property page, for a feature layer, is titled, "General" it appears because the custom layer implements the ILayer interface.  The association between "General" and ILayer is not mentioned in those recommended articles.

I will reduce my post to singular questions, as follows:
What interface(s) are required for the "Source" page?
What interface(s) are required for the "Selection" page?
What interface(s) are required for the "Display" page?
What interface(s) are required for the "Symbology" page?
What interface(s) are required for the "Fields" page?
What interface(s) are required for the "Definition Query" page?
What interface(s) are required for the "Labels" page?
What interface(s) are required for the "Join and Relates" page?
What interface(s) are required for the "Time" page?
What interface(s) are required for the "HTML Popup" page?

Respectfully,
Steve

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/use-existing-property-pages-with-new-ifeaturerenderer

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty well documented in the help. I would suggest reading these topics under [Application framework customizations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Application_framework_customizations/0001000003t5000000/) and [Mapping and visualization customizations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Mapping_and_visualization_customizations/000100000mmr000000/):

- [Creating property pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/0001/0001000004s7000000.htm)
- [How to create property pages and property sheets](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/0001/0001000000ns000000.htm)
- [Sample: Layer property page and property sheet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/0001/0001000000v1000000.htm)
- [Creating custom layers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Creating_custom_layers/0001000003v4000000/)
- [Sample: RSS Weather Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003n4000000)

Once you've gone through those, if you still have questions I would suggest creating a new question to address those specifically.